# Secondary-y offsetted by 2 x-ticks

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

My goal is to plot two different plots on the same figure.

My code :

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/theaupoulat/vc_fundraising/master/levee2019.csv")

# format amount raised
df["amount_raised"] = (df["amount_raised"]
                   .str.replace("M", "000000")
                   .str.replace(" ", "")
                   .str.replace(".", "")
                   .str.replace("€", "")
                   .str.replace("NC", "0")
                   .str.replace('\D', '')
                   .astype(int)
                   ) / 1000000

# groupby object to extract aggregate values
per_week = df.groupby("week_number")

# dataframe creation for plotting purposes
d = {'weekly_amount': per_week.amount_raised.sum(), "total_fundraisings": per_week.size()}
df_week_recap = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#plotting
plt.figure()

ax1 = df_week_recap['weekly_amount'].plot(secondary_y = True, color = 'violet')
ax2 = df_week_recap["total_fundraisings"].plot(kind='bar', color = 'blue')

ax2.grid(True)
ax1.grid(False)
ax1.set_ylim([0,500])

plt.show()
```

generated the plot below:

[image: plot]

This is strange as the values displayed by the pink line are from the [same row + 2] than the bar plot (checked the data).

I can't really understand where matplotlib decided to offset the DataFrame values.

Any clues ?

Thanks !

Comment: You may get more traction on this if you label w/ the pandas tag, since pandas is doing the plotting here, not directly matplotlib.

Comment: Unless you provide a runnable code, it is hard to guess what is wrong. Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The index of your dataframe starts at 2, so the line starts at position 2 as well.

Comment: hey, modified tag and added the whole code for re-creation.

@ImportanceOfBeingErnest I don't think it is that: with the same treatment, other libraries plot correctly the line (without offset)

Comment: You may think what you want, but even without knowing your dataframe, I can assure you that this is what happens. Your index starts at 2, so that is where the line starts. Bar plots always start at position 0. If you don't like that behaviour, other libraries indeed handle this differently, so e.g. using plain matplotlib for plotting  (`plt.bar` / `plt.plot`) would give you a more consistent visual.